# IE10 Dropdown menu is hiding behind Reports

Tags: drop-down-menu, z-index

My dropdown css menu is hiding behind Reports as shown in the figure...For reports we used  control to display report.

I have applied Z-index but it is of no use.....!

Answer (score 0):

z-index works only for non-static positioned elements. Try adding position: relative to the element you applied z-index to, and make sure the z-index value is high enough compared to the masking element. You can start trying with a z-index of 1000.